# Why are my pictures on my website different on my phone than on my desktop?

Tags: image, mobile

My problem is that my images from my site are loaded diffrent on my phone than they are on my desktop ( witch is the last updated version ) . The thing is , I've recently updated my host server ( cPanel ) with some new photos ( the ones seen on the desktop version ) and some of the old ones are still on the phone version . The wierd part is that some got updated on phone some don't . I don't think you can access my site but there it is to see on your own http://carolandhouse.ro/ .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using accelerated mobile pages (AMP)?
Have you deleted the cached files on your phone and tried looking at it?

Sometimes the image size / load time plays into what it shown on mobile. Large files can drag down the loading speed, and they may not load at all upon page-load. That can cause your website look different on mobile due to its lower processing power than a desktop.

Comment: No I am not using any AMPS , and about cache memory the thing is I've checked on other devices and it looks the same .